# Javascript : how to get the name of the instance?

Tags: javascript, object, instance

I create a class called foo :

```
foo = function()
{
...
}
```

Then I create an object called pear from the foo class :

```
pear = new foo();
```

Then I put the pear object in array :

```
array_obj = [pear];
```

So when I parse the array_obj by a "for loop", I want to get the name of the instance, that is say "pear" string :

```
for(var i = 0; i < array_obj.length; i++)
{
    console.log(array_obj[i].name);
}
```

But it doesn't work because `array_obj[i].name` doesn't return "pear" name.

Have you an idea ? Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: Consider the following valid JS code for a moment: `pear = apple = new foo()`

Comment: You may be confusing this for [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) which is new ES6 functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function:

```
foo = function(name)
{
   this.name = name;
}
```

And your call:

```
var pear = new foo("pear");
```

Comment: I'd get rid of the `var pear` (or change the name, at least) - it conflates the naming of the variable with the `.name` property of the object.

Comment: ok, everybody says I can't do this. So I must use the Paulo solution. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.  1 - it doesn't work, and 2 - it's a "layer violation" for an object to know anything about the names of the variables that reference it.

Also, variable names are a convenience for the programmer.  They can change through programmer choice, or even be changed automatically by things like minifiers or obfuscators.

If the name really matters therefore, it either needs to become a property of the object itself (passed in the constructor, per @Paulo's answer), or you need to maintain a "hash" (aka "map") that maps "human readable names" to the individual objects:

```
var map_obj = { pear: new foo() };
```

You can then iterate over the keys of that map (  `Object.keys(map_obj)` ) to find each object by name.  However in this case each name must be unique - a map can't contain duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because

```
array_obj[i].name == pear.name == (new foo()).name
```

And it depends on what you return from `foo()` function. I suspect it will return `undefined` because you not define such property in `foo()`

You can use @Paulo solution